# LIBUSB for FTDI2232 to use I2C mode

Tags: i2c, libusb, ftdi

Please help me to support this question:
Due to, we have used FTDI2232H and need to use “LIBUSB" to control FTDI2232H.
I want to ask How to control FTDI2232H related programs/code through LIBUSB.

1.To change MPSS mode to interface2?
2.To open iic and init it?
3.To set clock rate & set master mode?
4.The master write I2C code to slave ?
5.The master read I2C code from slave ?

I want to know how to use LIBUSB(libusb_bulk_transfer、libusb_control_transfer) to control FTDI2232H?
Please anyone can help me to solve my problem,I can not get full information from vendor here!!!

Comment: If you mean your chip name "FT2232H" it is easy to search and get example code at [ftdichip](https://ftdichip.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this open-source library to talk with the FTDI: https://github.com/lipro/libftdi

Download and unzip it and then just follow the procedure on the README.

Once you finish it, if you are on build you can:

cd examples

make

Now you just load your examples on the terminal like using './'
You can also modify as you want and then remake those examples.